# Heaps of trouble

Tags: code-golf, data-structures

## Challenge

You must, in the least bytes possible, implement the Binary Heap data structure and each of the following methods that operate on it:

- A function which takes no arguments and returns an empty Heap
- A function which takes a list of arguments with an arbitrary length and returns a Heap containing the elements
- A function which takes two Heaps and merges them into a new Heap, returning it
- A function which removes the root element of the Heap and reorders it accordingly, returning the root and new Heap
- A function which takes an integer and a Heap, inserts it into the Heap, and returns the Heap

## Clarifications

- Your heap must be implemented as linking nodes created with structs, classes, custom types or equivalent, not using an array or list
- You may implement either a max-heap or a min-heap, it is your choice.
- You may assume that only integers are being stored in the heap
- Your functions must be bound to a variable or name (and callable, obviously)
- Standard loopholes are disallowed

### Resources

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

Comment: No builtins, I'm guessing?

Comment: @Sp3000 Any built in heap type or methods operating on that type are disallowed, yes.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell - 217

Golfed version

```
data H=H H Int H|E
l E=0
l(H a _ b)=1+l a+l b
i E x=H E x E
i(H a y b)x|l a>l b=H a u$i b v|1>0=H(i a v)u b where(u,v)|x>y=(x,y)|1>0=(y,x)
f=foldl i E
t E=[]
t(H a x b)=x:t a++t b
m a b=f$t a++t b
p(H a x b)=(x,m a b)
```

Same, but with meaningfull names. Straightforward heap implemented as a binary tree, it can be either `Empty` or `Heap leftBranch element rightBranch`.

```
data Heap=Heap Heap Int Heap|Empty
len Empty=0
len(Heap a _ b)=1+len a+len b
insert Empty x=Heap Empty x Empty
insert(Heap a y b)x
    |len a>len b=Heap a u$insert b v
    |1>0=Heap(insert a v)u b
    where 
        (u,v)|x>y=(x,y)
             |1>0=(y,x)
fromList=foldl insert Empty
toList Empty=[]
toList(Heap a x b)=x:toList a++toList b
merge a b=fromList$toList a++toList b
pop(Heap a x b)=(x,merge a b)
```

Comment: I'm largely unfamiliar with Haskell so I'm having some trouble following this. Could you please add some explanation?

Comment: @Alex It is very readable code without any haskell knowledge imo. Functions perform pattern matching on the `Heap` datatype and do the obvious things :)

Answer (score -1):

### Lua - 275 (Already lost :D)

```
function f(s)return loadstring(s)end;f(([[a=f"_{}"b=f"t={...}&sort(t)_t"c=f"z={...}_f('x={'..&concat(z[1],',')..','..&concat(z[2],',')..'}&sort(x)_x')()"d=f"z={...}z=z[1]r=z[#z]&remove(z,#z)_z,r"e=f"z={...}&insert(z[1],z[2])_z[1]"]]):gsub("&","table."):gsub("_","return "))()
```

How it works:

```
function newHeap()
    return {}
end
function insertItemsToHeap(...)
    heap = {...}
    table.sort(heap)
    return heap
end
function margeHeaps(heap1, heap2)
    x = loadstring("return {"..table.concat(heap1,",")..","..table.concat(heap2,",").."}")()
    table.sort(x)
    return x
end
function removeRoot(...)
    z = {...}
    z = z[1]
    r = z[#z]
    table.remove(z,#z)
    return z, r
end
function insertInt(heap, int)
    table.insert(heap, int)
    return heap
end
```

Note: I have no previous experience with Binary Heaps once however, hope this is right.

Comment: Invalid because it is using arrays instead of data structures. See the clarifications

Comment: Lua tables are not arrays (list of items with a specific type/size) but more like objects (list of keys with values of any type). Moreover, people argue that Lua tables are a class like data structure, because their metatables allow for complex class-like behavior (Operator overloads, stuff like that). I did use the built-in table library, but that was not disallowed.

Comment: It wasn't implemented with a custom class, type, or struct. It's an invalid solution.