# Is it a heapable sequence?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, data-structures

A [binary max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) is a rooted tree with integer labeled nodes such that:

- No node has more than 2 children.
- The label of every node is greater than all of its children.

We say a sequence of integers is **[heapable](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.2365.pdf)** if there exists a binary max heap, whose labels are the sequence's elements, such that if \$p\$ is the parent of \$n\$, then the sequence has \$p\$ before \$n\$.

Alternatively, a sequence is heapable if there is a way to initialize a binary max heap whose root is its first element, and then insert the remaining elements one at a time in the order they appear in the sequence, while maintaining the binary max heap property.

For example:

- The sequence `[100, 19, 17, 36, 25, 3, 2, 1, 7]` is heapable, with [this heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Max-Heap-new.svg) showing why. In the heap, `19` is the parent of `3`, and `19` comes in the sequence before `3` does. This is true for any parent and child.
- The sequence `[100, 1, 2, 3]` is not heapable. If the sequence was heapable, each parent must be both larger, and come before, any of its children. Thus, the only possible parent of `1`, `2`, and `3` is `100`. But this is impossible in a binary heap, as each parent has at most two children.

Given a non-empty array of distinct positive integers, determine if it is heapable.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize your source code as measured in bytes.

### Test cases

```
[4, 1, 3, 2] -> True
[10, 4, 8, 6, 2] -> True
[100, 19, 17, 36, 25, 3, 2, 1, 7] -> True
[6, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4] -> True

[100, 1, 2, 3] -> False
[10, 2, 6, 4, 8] -> False
[10, 8, 4, 1, 5, 7, 3, 2, 9, 6] -> False
```

Notes:

- The typical [array representation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85079/is-it-a-max-heap) of a heap is a heapable sequence, but not all heapable sequences are in this form (as the above examples show).
- Most sources define heapable sequences with a min heap, rather than a max heap. It's not a big difference, but I imagine programmers are more familiar with max heaps than min heaps.
- This is a [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem) standard rules apply.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24869/103205).

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 100 bytes

```haskell
x!(q@(n,y):z)=[(2,x):(n-1,y):z|y>x,n>0]++map(q:)(x!z)
x!_=[]
g(x:y)=[]<foldl((.(!)).(>>=))[[(2,x)]]y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczRCsIgFIDhe59CoYtzmA1dd5LSe4iEsFoj57bq4jh6d4u6/eH7b/F5v6RUKwlYT5BlQbOh9dBJQgN5r3/lXRzJ7FRomikusBoEEhsyEmfrAxuATPmqcLzOqU8ALQjEFpyziP4/C6HUKY7Z9jPjfHmM@cV3fOBeKyW17OQh1A8)

### Explanation

We look for a heap using breadth first search. We keep track of the nodes and the number of available children in a list.  We discard any nodes that already have two children.  They are just not necessary any more since we only care about *if* there is a solution, not what it is.

At each step we attempt to insert a value at every location allowing it if we find a node with available children and a value greater than the value we are inserting.

If we manage to find a way to insert every value then we return `True` otherwise `False`.

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 35 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
{⟨⟩:1;×⊑⍒?0;∨´∧´¨¨¨⊔⟜v¨⥊↕2¨v←1↓}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge+KfqOKfqToxO8OX4oqR4o2S8J2VqT8wO+KIqMK04oinwrTCqPCdlYrCqMKo4oqU4p+cdsKo4qWK4oaVMsKoduKGkDHihpPwnZWpfQoKRsKo4p+oCjTigL8x4oC/M+KAvzIKMTDigL804oC/OOKAvzbigL8yCjEwMOKAvzE54oC/MTfigL8zNuKAvzI14oC/M+KAvzLigL8x4oC/NwoKMTAw4oC/MeKAvzLigL8zCjEw4oC/MuKAvzbigL804oC/OAoxMOKAvzjigL804oC/MeKAvzXigL834oC/M+KAvzLigL854oC/Ngrin6k=)

**Commented**

```
{
  ⟨⟩:1   ;  # The empty sequence is heapable
  ×⊑⍒?0 ;  # Not heapable if the maximum is not at index 0
  v←1↓     # Now consider the sequence without the first value
  ∨´        # It is heapable if any ...
  ⊔⟜v¨⥊↕2¨v #   ... way of splitting it
  ∧´¨¨¨    #   ... results in two heapable subsequences
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 81 bytes

Returns \$0\$ or \$1\$.

```javascript
f=([v,...a],t=[2**32-3])=>!v|t.some((x,i)=>x/4>v&x%4<2&&f(a,b=[...t,v*4],b[i]++))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZA9T8MwEIZ3foUZSOz06pCPJkUiHRETE5u5wSkOBIW4akyUgf8eXFeVWpQgYekW3z2@18@H7GW33dc7s2z1qxrHqqCiB865RDCFiIMgiZcJsmJz3X8b3ulPRekAtb0YwnTTe8NNeh97XkUllIWwoIE@SBFKUeNiwdi41W2nG8Ub/UZ98ajkTpaNQp9dnXcqKlIgEZAESIxk6jBGwpA877/UbzK6BWLpNZBskv6LtGh0Zyu3qw/06hjBZclxnszc0OqUOcX5nReo/9KKJ23I@7yIYyj3foKzIh5k002aiJ2Ggw/8L7p2XOT@lZ9EWDsZXqDjDw)

#### How?

We don't really need to keep track of the exact structure of the binary tree. In particular, we don't need to 'remember' the parent of a given node as long as we are sure that it was a valid connection when we added it.

We store the tree as a list of integers where the 2 least significant bits represent the number of child nodes and the higher bits represent the value of the node.

For instance a \$6\$ with 1 child node is stored as \$25\$:

```
11001
\_/\/
 |  \_ 1 child node
 +---- value = 6
```

We do a recursive search, looking for all valid parents for a given value. For each valid connection, we update the parent and simply add the child at the end of the list.

The list is initialized with a pseudo node whose value is \$2^{32}-3\$ so that the root node can be attached to it:

```
11111111111111111111111111111101
\____________________________/\/
              |                \_ 1 child
              +------------------ max. possible value with
                                  this encoding scheme
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 170 bytes:

```py
def f(v):
 q=[({v.pop(0):[]},v)]
 while q:
  r,V=q.pop(0)
  if[]==V:return 1
  for i in r:
   if i>V[0] and len(r[i])<2:q+=[({**r,i:r[i]+[V[0]],V[0]:[]},V[1:])]
 return 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BioMwFEX3fsVbJu2jGG3VCbWf4SZkMVBDAyXG4FiGod9uX9J2YHAWBrz35J747@kyuLLxYVnOvQHDZi4zGFvFfuadHzzLuVT6jjPXGdwu9trDSAAE7NrxBdCvNUq3bSdDP30FB4IiMwSwYB2EyBMB9tSpXMOnO8O1dywoq/mxkOM22jabgFbGbKsipjGeyd0pIXX0v9bzxQfrJmaY2iMIhBKh0Jxnv7HIEahqEKp1RZ34oK@mi7E@PAfSUv2HrVJ8eDv2/wwlolzJi2SOT1hVTcpF2q3fanpPReTyAA)

Comment: [154](https://tio.run/##bY7BasMwEETv/oo9Ss5SIjuxXRH1M3wROijEJoIgy8JxKaHf7q7VplDcg2A1b3Zmw8d0HXzZhLgsl66Hns1cZjAqzR7zSxgC23OpzSfO3GTwfnW3DkYyQMRWjT8G@rpeG6VaGbvpHj0IkizmZ9XS0A8RHDgPcV0kK9w6z6J2hp8K6y/g3qwcd4o98jyikyvZaWvQpuYzxyVE5yfWM31AEAglQmE4z35lsUcg1CBUW0RMvNKraXHFx@@AlFT/8VZJPj47Dv8EJUe5KS9S83rCBjVJFym3flbTPRU5ly8)